# Undefined nested values in an non-empty object in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-context, azure-ad-msal

I started react recently and work with it on a new app, using Msal auth.
I created a context to keep the user informations updated and use them wherever I need. It's working perfectly until **I refresh the page**.

The issue is : I have my object with all informations but when I want to display one value, it's "undefined" (even if it's existing in object), until a re-render is made on the page (open the menu, change page with router, ...). It cause that where I need to display these values, all is just empty and I need to make something in the page to show them. That's not really user-friendly...

My UserContext.js

```
import { useIsAuthenticated as isAuthenticated } from "@azure/msal-react";
import { createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useMsal } from "@azure/msal-react";
import { msalConfig } from "../authConfig";


const initUser = () => ({
    ADuserdatas : {
        homeAccountId : "",
        accountEnabled : "",
        companyName : "",
        createdDateTime : "",
        department : "",
        displayName : "",
        givenName : "",
        id : "",
        jobTitle : "",
        mail : "",
        mobilePhone : "",
        officeLocation : "",
        surname : "",
        userType : "",
    },
    language : "en"
})
const UserDatasFromMS = ({ instance, accounts }) => {
    
    let ADuserdatas = {};

    const callMsGraph = (token) => {
[...]
    }
    const handleUser = () => {
    instance
    .acquireTokenSilent({
        scopes: ["openid", "profile", "user.read"],
        account: accounts[0],
        authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${msalConfig.auth.tenantId}`,
    })
    .then((response) => {
        callMsGraph(response.accessToken).then((data) => {
            ADuserdatas.homeAccountId = response.account.homeAccountId;
            ADuserdatas.accountEnabled = data.accountEnabled;
            ADuserdatas.companyName = data.companyName;
            ADuserdatas.createdDateTime = data.createdDateTime;
            ADuserdatas.department = data.department;
            ADuserdatas.displayName = data.displayName;
            ADuserdatas.givenName = data.givenName;
            ADuserdatas.id = data.id;
            ADuserdatas.jobTitle = data.jobTitle;
            ADuserdatas.mail = data.mail;
            ADuserdatas.mobilePhone = data.mobilePhone;
            ADuserdatas.officeLocation = data.officeLocation;
            ADuserdatas.surname = data.surname;
            ADuserdatas.userType = data.userType;
        });
    });
    }
    handleUser();
    
    return {ADuserdatas}
    
};
export const UserContext = createContext({});

export const UserContextProvider = ({children}) => {
    const { instance, accounts } = useMsal();
    const [datasFromMS, setDatasFromMS] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        setDatasFromMS(isAuthenticated ? UserDatasFromMS({instance, accounts}) : initUser.ADuserdatas)
    }, [instance, accounts])
        
    return(
        <UserContext.Provider
        value={{
            datasFromMS, 
            setDatasFromMS,           
        }}
        >{children}</UserContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

Here's what the console show me **after refresh and before an other component re-render** :

With `console.log(datasFromMS)`:

```
{
    "ADuserdatas": {
        "homeAccountId": "Correct value",
        "accountEnabled": true,
        "companyName": "Correct value",
        "createdDateTime": "Correct value",
        "department": "IT",
        "displayName": "Correct value",
        "givenName": "Correct value",
        "id": "Correct value",
        "jobTitle": "Correct value",
        "mail": "Correct value",
        "mobilePhone": null,
        "officeLocation": "Correct value",
        "surname": "Correct value",
        "userType": "Correct value"
    }
}
```

With `console.log(datasFromMS?.ADuserdatas)`

```
{
    "homeAccountId": "Correct value",
    "accountEnabled": true,
    "companyName": "Correct value",
    "createdDateTime": "Correct value",
    "department": "IT",
    "displayName": "Correct value",
    "givenName": "Correct value",
    "id": "Correct value",
    "jobTitle": "Correct value",
    "mail": "Correct value",
    "mobilePhone": null,
    "officeLocation": "Correct value",
    "surname": "Correct value",
    "userType": "Correct value"
}
```

With `console.log(datasFromMS?.ADuserdatas?.companyName)`

`undefined`

I'm trying to fix this for days now, and tried a lot of possibilities : exported UserDatasFromMS(), arrays, objects, values in createContext, initUser in state, combine the context with a useUser hook, add the useState in App(), ... So much possibilities that I can't all list them.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is a misunderstanding of async code. When you call `UserDatasFromMS`, a promise is kicked off. That means that by the time that function is returned  for the first time, `ADuserdatas` will not even be set since the function returns before the promise resolves asynchronously. I would recommend reading about promises to understand this.

The solution is to have the promise resolve to the value you want then wait for it in the effect before setting the value in the component state.

```
import { useIsAuthenticated as isAuthenticated } from "@azure/msal-react"
import { createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react"
import { useMsal } from "@azure/msal-react"
import { msalConfig } from "../authConfig"

const initUser = () => ({
  ADuserdatas: {
    homeAccountId: "",
    accountEnabled: "",
    companyName: "",
    createdDateTime: "",
    department: "",
    displayName: "",
    givenName: "",
    id: "",
    jobTitle: "",
    mail: "",
    mobilePhone: "",
    officeLocation: "",
    surname: "",
    userType: "",
  },
  language: "en",
})
const UserDatasFromMS = ({ instance, accounts }) => {
  const callMsGraph = (token) => {}

  const handleUser = () =>
    instance
      .acquireTokenSilent({
        scopes: ["openid", "profile", "user.read"],
        account: accounts[0],
        authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${msalConfig.auth.tenantId}`,
      })
      .then((response) =>
        callMsGraph(response.accessToken).then((data) => ({
          homeAccountId: response.account.homeAccountId,
          accountEnabled: data.accountEnabled,
          companyName: data.companyName,
          createdDateTime: data.createdDateTime,
          department: data.department,
          displayName: data.displayName,
          givenName: data.givenName,
          id: data.id,
          jobTitle: data.jobTitle,
          mail: data.mail,
          mobilePhone: data.mobilePhone,
          officeLocatio: data.officeLocation,
          surname: data.surname,
          userType: data.userType,
        }))
      )

  return handleUser()
}
export const UserContext = createContext({})

export const UserContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const { instance, accounts } = useMsal()
  const [datasFromMS, setDatasFromMS] = useState(initUser.ADuserdatas)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isAuthenticated) return
    UserDatasFromMS({ instance, accounts }).then((ADuserdatas) =>
      setDatasFromMS({ ADuserdatas })
    )
  }, [instance, accounts])

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider
      value={{
        datasFromMS,
        setDatasFromMS,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I didn't thought about Promise, indeed. So I tried to adapt with what you sent but now I have an error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading "then")". Seems that the changes in UserDatasFromMS doesn't work. I'm checking what causes that "UserDatasFromMS" is now undefined.

Comment: ive edited it to fix -- (handleUser was using curly braces, it needed auto return to actually return the promise)

Answer (score 0):

I tried what said Adsy but was facing an error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading "then") because UserDatasFromMS were "undefined" in the useEffect.

So I finally exported my function handleUser and deleted the UserDatasfroMS (was useless) and fixed my issue with a new Promise like this :

```
export const handleUserAD = ({ instance, accounts }) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    instance
    .acquireTokenSilent({
      scopes: ["openid", "profile", "user.read"],
      account: accounts[0],
      authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${msalConfig.auth.tenantId}`,
    })
    .then((response) => {  
      callMsGraph(response.accessToken).then((data) => (
          {
        homeAccountId: response.account.homeAccountId,
        accountEnabled: data.accountEnabled,
        companyName: data.companyName,
        createdDateTime: data.createdDateTime,
        department: data.department,
        displayName: data.displayName,
        givenName: data.givenName,
        id: data.id,
        jobTitle: data.jobTitle,
        mail: data.mail,
        mobilePhone: data.mobilePhone,
        officeLocatio: data.officeLocation,
        surname: data.surname,
        userType: data.userType,
      })).then((ADuserdatas) => resolve(ADuserdatas)).catch((error) => {reject(error)})
    });
  
  })
```

Comment: If this builds on someone else's answer, either include the full answer in yours or leave a comment on the answer this builds from so they can improve theirs.